# grep weird behaviour in linux command line

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file test.txt which contains this text data

```
# cat test.txt
*@=>*@
```

if I use grep to check if the string is in the file using this way

```
# grep "*@=>*@" test.txt
#
```

it returns nothing..

while if I grep a partial string search

```
# grep "*@=>" test.txt
# *@=>*@
```

it works correctly ..

Why in the first case do grep return nothing ?

Comment: Use `-F`: `grep -F '*@=>*@' test.txt`

Comment: It is written in the manual (type `man grep` on your terminal): _"The grep utility searches any given input files, selecting lines that match one or more patterns.  By default, a pattern matches an input line if the regular expression (RE) in the pattern matches the input line without its trailing newline."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asterisk is special to `grep`, it means "the previous token is repeated zero or more times". So `>*` would match an empty string or `>` or `>>` etc.

To match an asterisk, backslash it in the pattern:

```
grep '\*@=>\*@' test.txt
```

(The first asterisk follows no token, so the backslash is optional.)